# setState cannot be called within function

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, flutter-web, setstate

I am trying to write a setState((){}) function in my code. But I am getting an error when I call it. I am trying to do the following

```
setState(() {
  index += 1;
});
```

When I try to do this, I am getting an error thrown

`The instance member 'setState' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

`Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression dartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer`

I'm not sure why this is happening, I can show you what I am doing here: I have an array of widgets, which require a function when a specific button in the widget is pressed. And with the first button being called, I want the index to be increased, and setState called, changing my UI. Instead, I get the weird error.

```
  var subpages = {
    0: LocationQuote(
      onNext: () {
        setState(() {
          index += 1;
        });
      },
    ),
    1: SizeQuote(
      onNext: () {
        print("size");
      },
    ),
    2: StoriesQuote(),
    3: InsuranceQuote(),
    4: SteepnessQuote(),
    5: FinishQuote(),
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access instance members in an initializer. As a work around you can try to set it in initState, for example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  subpages = ...
}
```